# How to use setState method for only one widget in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

On clicking on any point in the below graph, I want to show some information related to that point. But when I use `setState` method to update the below information on click event, the graph is getting rebuilt. I want to zoom in at a certain time in this time-series graph, but the rebuilding graph is a problem and not able to see labels on graph. How to use the `setState` method to update the below information without redrawing the graph?

In the below image `Angle` value should be `15.0` whereas it's not updating without `setState`

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `redrawing the graph is a problem`?

Comment: I think by redrawing the graph he means rebuilding the graph widget

Answer (score 13):

You could wrap your widget with [StatefulBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html):

> A platonic widget that both has state and calls a closure to obtain
>   its child widget.
>
> The StateSetter function passed to the builder is used to invoke a
>   rebuild instead of a typical State's State.setState.

Here is an example from the docs:

> ```
> await showDialog<void>(
>   context: context,
>   builder: (BuildContext context) {
>     int selectedRadio = 0;
>     return AlertDialog(
>       content: StatefulBuilder(
>         builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
>           return Column(
>             mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
>             children: List<Widget>.generate(4, (int index) {
>               return Radio<int>(
>                 value: index,
>                 groupValue: selectedRadio,
>                 onChanged: (int value) {
>                   setState(() => selectedRadio = value);
>                 },
>               );
>             }),
>           );
>         },
>       ),
>     );
>   },
> );
> ```

Comment: That widget is there mostly for test purposes, not for actual performance optimization

Comment: Do you have any official references about that?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/search?q=StatefulBuilder&unscoped_q=StatefulBuilder

Comment: I don't see that they say you should only use it for test purposes, and also in dialog.dart they mention: Use a [StatefulBuilder] or a custom [StatefulWidget] if the dialog needs to update dynamically https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/df4bf453abbd9244eec053bfd7a4117be8e0abfc/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dialog.dart

Comment: Btw, I think he is not asking this for performance optimization but to avoid rebuilding the parent widgets

Comment: Dialogs are different from the context of the question. StatefulBuilder only works correctly there because dialogs are on an entirely different branch of the widget tree.

Answer (score 7):

What I do to stop rebuilding some widgets is I move that widget into its own stateful widget. So it will not rebuild when it's parent rebuild. And to communicate between them I use callback functions or bloc pattern. So what you can do is you can move the graph to a seperate stateful widget and on cilck event you can pass the data through a fucntion callback to its parent.

Comment: i have my widget stored in  another stateful widget, Which they are called by a list view. But when i setState the main widget of affects the other stateful widget. And they are so many that they make app slow. CODE: MainStateFullWd......... `ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true, 
                      primary: false,
                      itemCount:unipost.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index){
                            return  Post(unipost[index])  ;//the name of statfkwidget am calling
                          }
                        ),`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Provider widget with its Consumer pattern to reduce which parts of the tree are rebuilt on changes.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use StreamBuilder, see the youtube video about it.

[click to see youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkKEWHfy99Y)

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering an old question for future readers.

I wonder why nobody pointed out the [`ValueListenableBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html) widget until now. You can rebuild only a text Widget like this.

```
class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  final clickedValue = ValueNotifier<double>(0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Wrap the existing text widget with the ValueListenableBuilder.
    final clickedValueText = ValueListenableBuilder<double>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, double value, Widget? child) {
        return Text('$value');
      },
      valueListenable: clickedValue,
    );
    ...
  }

  void onClickGraph(double value) {
    clickedValue.value = value; // This will trigger rebuiding the text widget.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is based on a misconception.

What you asked is  "don't call `build` again on XX widget".

But you're looking for is for two methods to not be called:

- RenderObject.layout
- RenderObject.paint

`setState` has no influence on that.

Calling `setState` won't necessarily repaint the associated widget tree. And the opposite is true too, there's no need for a `setState` for the widget tree to be repainted.

What you're looking for is for things like [RepaintBoundary](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RepaintBoundary-class.html), which allows part of the tree to not repaint if not needed.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, he is not asking how to avoid repainting but how to avoid rebuilding the whole tree of widgets

Comment: @PabloBarrera he did use the word "redraw" quite a few times. As for not calling "build" again, that doesn't matter. That's not what cause performance issues and we don't have to care about that.

Comment: I know, the thing is we understood the question differently. I think he don't want to redraw (rebuild) the graph because it may have some animation and you think he don't want to redraw (repaint) the graph because of performance issues.

Comment: Without him clarifying his question, then there's no point discussing about it.